# Summing columns with string match on dates

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe **df** with an ID variable and daily dates (format XYYYYMMDD) as column headers:

```
ID <- c(101,102,203,207,209)
X20170101 <- c(1,NA,NA,2,1)
X20170102 <- c(NA,1,1,1,NA)
X20170103<-c(NA,NA,NA,2,1)
X20170201<-c(NA,2,NA,NA,1)
X20170202<-c(NA,1,1,NA,NA)
X20170301<-c(NA,1,NA,NA,NA)
df <- data.table(ID,X20170101,X20170102,X20170103,X20170201,X20170202,X20170301)

 ID X20170101 X20170102 X20170103 X20170201 X20170202 X20170301
101         1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
102        NA         1        NA         2         1         1
203        NA         1        NA        NA         1        NA
207         2         1         2        NA        NA        NA
209         1        NA         1         1        NA        NA
```

For each ID, I would like to sum across all dates/columns belonging to the same month. If **yyyymm** is the vector of strings for the first three months

```
yyyymm <- c("X201701","X201702","X201703")
```

I would like to obtain the dataframe **want** with strings in yyyymm as headers of the columns. That is:

```
 ID X201701 X201702 X201703
101       1      NA      NA
102       1       3       1
203       1       1      NA
207       5      NA      NA
209       2       1      NA
```

My idea was to avoid reshaping the format of my dataset and use functions lapply and grepl to partially match the strings, but I'm missing something.

```
test = lapply(df, function(x) colSums(df[,grepl(x, names(df))]))
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one using `lubridate` package to parse dates and `split.default` to divide data.frame into groups based on same month

```
library(lubridate)
factors = sapply(ymd(gsub("X", "", names(df)[-1])), function(x)
    paste0(year(x), sprintf("%02d", as.integer(month(x)))))
data.frame(df[,1],
           lapply(split.default(df[,-1], factors), function(x)
               rowSums(x, na.rm = TRUE) * (NA^(rowSums(is.na(x)) == NCOL(x)))))
#   ID X201701 X201702 X201703
#1 101       1      NA      NA
#2 102       1       3       1
#3 203       1       1      NA
#4 207       5      NA      NA
#5 209       2       1      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to spread your data?

```
library(tidyverse)
want <- df %>%
          gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
          mutate(key = substr(key, 1, 7)) %>%
          group_by(ID, key) %>%
          summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
          spread(key, value)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ID [5]
     ID X201701 X201702 X201703
* <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1   101       1       0       0
2   102       1       3       1
3   203       1       1       0
4   207       5       0       0
5   209       2       1       0
```